# How to get entire page height in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

and not just the browser screen height?

clientHeight only returns the height of the window!

thanks :]

Comment: `screen.height` , `screen.availHeight` if you want it minus the sides. If you want to include content then `document.height`

Comment: document.body.offsetHeight

Comment: Why ask something you can 'google' in 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the height of your entire document:

```
document.height
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of the document:

`document.height`

Answer (score -1):

try it with jquery:

```
$('body').height(); //returns viewport height
```

Comment: Please do not answer with jQuery on non-jQuery questions (note the tags) at least without asking OP if it's ok - it is considered bad mannered here. There is no reason to include an entire huge library for this.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - amen!

Comment: ...just trying to help.

Comment: @lenswipe I know, I was not implying otherwise. I appreciate your attempt to help but answering non-jquery questions with jQuery is encouraging dependency in a library rather than understanding the fundamental basics of the environment.